# How can I get the output I am looking for using this SQL statement

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have this SQL statement that is attempting to union the results of two queries.

```
SELECT s.SectionIndex, COUNT(*) AS [# Drops], s.Name AS section_name, c.DisplayName AS course_name
FROM Enrollments e
JOIN Sections s on s.SectionIndex = e.SectionIndex
JOIN Courses c on c.CourseIndex = s.CourseIndex

WHERE (CAST(StartDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2014-06-30' AND '2015-06-30') AND   (e.Status like 'DROPPED%')
GROUP BY s.SectionIndex, s.Name, c.DisplayName

UNION ALL

SELECT s.SectionIndex, COUNT(*) AS [# Completes], s.Name AS section_name, c.DisplayName AS course_name
FROM Enrollments e
JOIN Sections s on s.SectionIndex = e.SectionIndex
JOIN Courses c on c.CourseIndex = s.CourseIndex

WHERE (CAST(StartDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2014-06-30' AND '2015-06-30') AND (e.Status like 'complete%')

GROUP BY s.SectionIndex, s.Name, c.DisplayName
ORDER BY s.SectionIndex
```

The result set looks like this, which I believe is accurate.  For example, for SectionIndex 996, The drops were 3 and completions 1.  The First 4 sections only had drops in them.

Result set.

[image]
**What I would really like is the output like this.**

```
SectionIndex xxx
  # drops xx
  # completions xx
SectionIndex xxx
  # drops xx
  # completions xx
```

.
.
.

thank you for thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not what SQL can offer you (at least as far as I understand your question). All SQL results are cursors than have common structure for every row.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague helped me to look at this question differently.  This SQL combined the two queries into a single set, without *mashing them together like the UNION was doing.

```
select *
 from
 (
  select coalesce(q1.SectionIndex,q2.SectionIndex) as sectionIndex, coalesce(q1.section_name, q2.section_name) as sectionName
 , q1.completions, q2.drops

   from

    (
     select e.SectionIndex, s.Name as section_name, COUNT(e.SectionIndex) as completions
     from Enrollments e
     join Sections s on s.SectionIndex = e.SectionIndex
     join Courses c on c.CourseIndex = s.CourseIndex
     where e.Status like 'COMPLETED'
     AND (CAST(StartDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2014-06-30' AND '2015-06-30')
     group by e.SectionIndex, s.Name
    ) as q1

/*UNION*/

 full outer join 

   (
    select e.SectionIndex, s.Name as section_name, COUNT(e.SectionIndex) as drops
    from Enrollments e
    join Sections s on s.SectionIndex = e.SectionIndex
    where e.Status like 'dropped'
    AND (CAST(StartDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2014-06-30' AND '2015-06-30')
    group by e.SectionIndex, s.Name
   ) as q2

 on q1.SectionIndex = q2.SectionIndex

) as q3

order by q3.sectionName
```

Resulted into output like this, in a single result set.

[image]